# Is it possible to reuse hyperlink defined in another file in restructuredtext (or sphinx)

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Suppose I have two files `a.rst` and `b.rst` in the same folder, and `a.rst` looks like this

```
.. _foo: http://stackoverflow.com

`foo`_ is a website
```

It seems using `foo` in `b.rst` is not allowed. Is there a way to define hyperlinks and use them in multiple files?

> Followup

I used the `extlinks` extension as Steve Piercy suggested. Its implementation and docstring can be seen [here on github](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/extlinks.py).

In my case, I define wikipedia link in my conf.py

```
extlinks = {'wiki': ('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%s', '')}
```

and in the `.rst` files, use them like

```
:wiki:`Einstein <Albert_Einstein>`
```

where Einstein will be displayed as a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least four possible solutions.

#### 1. repeat yourself

Put your complete reST in each file.  You probably don't want that.

#### 2. combined `rst_epilog` and substitution

This one is clever. Configure the [`rst_epilog`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog) value, in your `conf.py` along with a [substition with the `replace` directive](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#replacement-text):

```py
rst_epilog = """
.. |foo| replace:: foo
.. _foo: http://stackoverflow.com
"""
```

and reST:

```
|foo|_ is a website
```

yields:

```html
<a class="reference external" href="http://stackoverflow.com">foo</a>
```

#### 3. `extlinks`

For links to external websites where you want to have a base URL and append path segments or arguments, you can use [`extlinks`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/ext/extlinks.html) in your `conf.py`:

```py
extensions = [
...
    'sphinx.ext.extlinks',
...
]
...
extlinks = {'so': ('https://stackoverflow.com/%s', None)}
```

Then in your reST:

```
:so:`questions/49016433`
```

Yields:

```html
<a class="reference external"
 href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016433">
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016433
</a>
```

#### 4. `intersphinx`

For external websites that are documentation generated by Sphinx, then you can use [`intersphinx`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/latest/ext/intersphinx.html), in your `conf.py`:

```py
extensions = [
...
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
...
]
...
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3', None),
}
```

Then in your reST:

```
:py:mod:`doctest`
```

Yields:

```html
<a class="reference external"
 href="https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#module-doctest"
 title="(in Python v3.6)">
    <code class="xref py py-mod docutils literal">
        <span class="pre">doctest</span>
    </code>
</a>
```

Comment: 5. a separate file for with the link targets, included in all documents that require them. Works also with plain Docutils (as explained in the answer by Martí)

Answer (score 4):

This might come a bit late but I have found a solution that works very neatly for me and it is not among the answers already given.

In my case, I create a file with all the links used in my project, save it as `/include/links.rst`, and looking something like:

```
.. _PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
.. _numpydoc: https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html
.. _googledoc: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html
```

Then there are the files `a.rst` and `b.rst` looking like:

```
.. include:: /include/links.rst

File A.rst
##########

Click `here <PEP8_>`_ to see the PEP8 coding style

Alternatively, visit either:
    - `Numpy Style <numpydoc_>`_
    - `Google Style <googledoc_>`_
```

and

```
.. include:: /include/links.rst

File B.rst
##########

You can visit `Python's PEP8 Style Guide <PEP8_>`_

For docstrings, you can use either `Numpy's <numpydoc_>`_ or `Google's <googledoc_>`_
```

respectively.

The produced output for both cases is:

[image]

and

[image]

respectively.

Moreover, I would like to emphasize the fact of which I was actually really struggling to achieve, to use different names (displayed text) for the same link at different locations and which I have achieved with the double `_`, one inside the `<..._>` and another outside.

Comment: Cleanest solution here. Can't believe Sphinx doesn't have this functionality in a more formal way

Comment: Clean solution. Works great, particularly for linking with different displayed text for same link in different locations. Thanks!!!

Comment: Go one step further by "including" the include file in your doc set once by setting it up in `conf.py`. See `rst_epilog` and the `include` role.

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution: it is a bit hacky and a little bit different respect to the officially supported way to share external links.

First complete the **Setup** then:

1. in `conf.py` add the `commonlinks` entry in `extensions`
2. in `conf.py` configure the map of common links:

For example:

```
extensions = [
    ...,
    'sphinx.ext.commonlinks'
]

commonlinks = {
                'issues': 'https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues',
                'github': 'https://github.com'
              }
```

Then in .rst files you can do these:

```
The :github:`_url_` url is aliased to :github:`GitHub` and also to :github:`this`
```

### Setup

All that is needed is to copy into `sphinx/ext` directory the file `commonlinks.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    sphinx.ext.commonlinks
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    Extension to save typing and prevent hard-coding of common URLs in the reST
    files.

    This adds a new config value called ``commonlinks`` that is created like this::

       commonlinks = {'exmpl': 'http://example.com/mypage.html', ...}

    Now you can use e.g. :exmpl:`foo` in your documents.  This will create a
    link to ``http://example.com/mypage.html``.  The link caption depends on the
    role content:

    - If it is ``_url_``, the caption will be the full URL.
    - If it is a string, the caption will be the role content.

"""

from six import iteritems
from docutils import nodes, utils

import sphinx
from sphinx.util.nodes import split_explicit_title


def make_link_role(base_url):
    def role(typ, rawtext, text, lineno, inliner, options={}, content=[]):
        text = utils.unescape(text)
        if text == '_url_':
            title = base_url
        else:
            title = text
        pnode = nodes.reference(title, title, internal=False, refuri=base_url)
        return [pnode], []
    return role


def setup_link_roles(app):
    for name, base_url in iteritems(app.config.commonlinks):
        app.add_role(name, make_link_role(base_url))


def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('commonlinks', {}, 'env')
    app.connect('builder-inited', setup_link_roles)
    return {'version': sphinx.__display_version__, 'parallel_read_safe': True}
```

To locate the `sphinx` installation directory one way is:

```
$ python 3
> import sphinx
> sphinx
<module 'sphinx' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/__init__.py'>
```

then:

```
% cp commonlinks.py /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sphinx/ext
```