# Dynamic URLs using rst_epilog in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution

I have been working on Sphinx documentation using python recently. In my documentation I have some dynamic URLs that will be updated on each built of the docs and comes from a DB which I have already configured and working fine. These values are included in `rst_epilog` in `conf.py` like this.

```py
rst_epilog = """
.. |value1| replace:: www.google.com
.. |value2| replace:: www.fb.com
"""
```

Inside my documentation I'm using something like this

```
For more information search `here`_

.. _`here`: |value1|
```

But some how the `|value1|` is not replaced with `www.google.com` (it works fine in paragraphs) and it becomes an internal link.

If there is something wrong I'm doing or there is a work around this problem then I can work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned by Steve in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49016433/is-it-possible-to-reuse-hyperlink-defined-in-another-file-in-restructuredtext-o). One can use substitution and rst_epilog together. For above example the changes will look something like this

In conf.py

```py
rst_epilog = """
.. |value1| replace:: value1
.. _value1: www.google.com
.. |value2| replace:: value2
.. _value2: www.fb.com
"""
```

And in .rst file

```
For more information search |value1|_
```

This will result in substitution and then hyperlink generation dynamically for rst_epilog.