# Link a Sphinx substitution

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, cross-reference

I have a Sphinx project, with some substitutions. I have a variable `|total_downloads|` (which works fine) on which I want to link some section `statistics`. I tried the following two pieces of code:

```
:ref:`|total_downloads| <statistics>`
```

and

```
:ref:`\ |total_downloads|\  <statistics>`
```

which both create correctly correctly the link, but display `|total_downloads|` instead of the content of the variable.

Is there any way to solve this issue?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: reStructuredText does not support nested interpretation in its markup.

Comment: @StevePiercy Does this mean that there is no way to do this?

Comment: Correct. However, there might be a combination of `rst_epilog` and a substitution. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49019210/2214933. Additionally, there might be some custom directive that you could write, or a Python function to replace the output after it is rendered to HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is in the comment, as @StevePiercy says, restructuredtext does not support anything other than plain text inside its links.

My advice would be to change it to say something like "1234 downloads (`see full statistics <statistics>`_)" so that both the information, and the link to the supporting section, are both clear.

Answer (score 0):

While reStructuredText currently does not support nested inline markup, it allows the use of substitutions in simple hyperlink references:

```
.. |today| date::

Both, |today|__ and |today|_ produce a link with the current date as text.

__ example.com
.. _today: example.org
```

I cannot tell, whether this also works for the `|total_downloads|` variable.

Hint: substitutions can also be used as a workaround to get emphasized or otherwise styled link text (see [reStructuredText Directives](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html)).